# Angular ui route based on URL path + hash path

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use the UI router to display a different template for the following path. I'm adding the full URL so you can see exactly what the intention is.

Basically I want the router to account for the actual URL path, but right now no template gets detected and the state provider redirects to `/` instead.

```
http://localhost/dashboard/#home
```

And this is what goes in to the `$stateProvider`.

```
.state('dashboard.home', {
   url: '/home',
   path: 'dashboard',
   templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard/home'
})
```

Comment: Are you aware of it that "Dot notation" (dashboard.home) is used for child state? means, withour "dashboard" state, you can not register child state?

Comment: I have never heard about this feature (`path`). Do you have a reference where I can read about it?

Comment: @Asik Even if I simply name it dashboard, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I guess, dashboard is your directory name.. index.html is inside this dashboard folder. So you should register with "home"...not "dashboard"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [plunker with example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9gX28mgFXB9DoAuS4Ki?p=preview). In general, we can have parent child like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
  })
$stateProvider
  .state('dashboard.home', {
    url: '/home2',
    path: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard/home'
  })
```

What we can see, there is a parent state 'dashboard' (in this case without url defined) and there is its child 'dashboard.home', which url here is `url: '/home2'`. So going to #/home2, we will reach this state

Or we can use this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('dashboard_home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard/home'
  })
```

This is state without a parent. That's why it cannot contain `dashboard.`, which would be evaluated as: "find parent with name 'dashboard'"

And these states are working when clicked this link:

```
<a href="#/home">
<a href="#/home2">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9gX28mgFXB9DoAuS4Ki?p=preview)